# Internet connectivity in Android

Tags: android, http, ping

Is there a better option than the below, to check the connectivity on internet. I know Wifi or Mobile data is connected but I would like to know if my app is able to connect to internet to receive data:

```
class checkInternetNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        internetavailable = isInternetConnected();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
    {

        if (internetavailable == false)
        {
            Log.e("Check","internetavailable");

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect to server. Check your network!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

I have the isInternetConnected method like this:

```
  public boolean isInternetConnected() 
{
    final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    try 
    {
        HttpURLConnection mURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        mURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "ConnectionTest");
        mURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        mURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        mURLConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        mURLConnection.connect();
        return (mURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {

    }
    return false;

}
```

The problem is internetAvailable is always showing false.

A solution to this would be really useful.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to amend your codes to check for other locations in case Google's servers are unreachable - however unlikely.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I am always getting false when the internet seems to slow. How to fix this up?

Comment: Your `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` value is set to one second - this is not enough time to poll a server and get a response back. You need to set it to like four or five seconds.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely an easy way to do it. The better way would be to actually check the web service you're trying to use. Because hypothetically, Google.com could be down and your web service still be working, or vice versa, Google.com could be working and your web service could be down.

You can also try: ([See Documentation:](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) Use "ConnectivityManager to query the active network and determine if it has Internet connectivity.")

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the problem with the above code is that it takes more that 5 seconds to return true or false. hence sometime even if I have internet I am getting false.

Comment: @TheDevMan see the update. But even if you have internet, it's sometimes helpful to check the web service. Otherwise you might have to wait for the default timeout error.

Comment: This will only give if the wifi or data is enabled, this doesn't check the server for data connectivity right?

Comment: According to the Android Documentation, ConnectivityManager should "query the active network and determine if it has Internet connectivity."
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: So are you saying I don't need to check my server? I just have isOnline() method implemented that is all?

Comment: The reason for to check internet is because I am using Json to get some data from server. If internet is not there app is force closing? I am not sure how to handle that situation.

Comment: isOn line only checks for internet connectivity. It does not check your specific server.

Comment: Thanks! Just clarification again will your isOnline code check connectivitiy of wifi or data or will check if my phone can access the websites etc?

Comment: isOnline will only check for connectivity of WiFi or data.

Comment: "If internet is not there app is force closing? I am not sure how to handle that situation". although it's good practice to check `isConnected()`, it doesn't guarantee that your app still won't force close. Connections can at any time throw an `IOException` for any reason. You should be catching the exception and **treating in an appropriate way**

Answer (score 0):

you should query the ConnectivityManager for stuff like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo;
boolean isConnected = ni != null && ni.isConnected()
```

make sure to check the docs for ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo because there's a lot more data you can get there:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro, Create a class named CheckNetwork. Place my checker code below inside the class.

```
private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "no internet connection");
        return false;
    } else {
        if (info.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, " internet connection available...");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, " internet connection");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Check the network connectivity in your class like this

> if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(YourClass.this)) {
>
> //do if have internet
>
> }
>
> else {
>
> //do if no internet connection
>
> }

Do the necessary imports. If ever you are trying to access a wrong URL please make sure it checks whether the "json" or whichever data transfer you are fetching has value otherwise it will return nullpointerexception as well. Hope this helps. Cheers.